# How to know when scroll down has reached the end of the page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to scroll down incrementally in order to find a task in a page.
I'd like to shorten the execution time by knowing when I reached the end of the page. That way I can stop searching and return "task is not found".

I'm using chromedriver.

This is currently my code:

```
boolean isTaskExist = false;
do{
    isTaskExist = isElementPresent(driver, By.xpath(checkBoxXpath),2);
    if(!isTaskExist){
              scrollWindow.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
              Thread.sleep(500);
              report.report("scrolling down to find task " + taskName);
    }
}while((!isTaskExist) && (System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime+180000));
```

Comment: is there any problem if u scroll to element automatically?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the purpose of to scrolling down while WebDriver automatically search and scroll to that element which you want to search if element exist on the page???

Comment: @SaurabhGaur The reason I need to scroll down the page is since the driver cannot find them unless I scroll down. I know.. it surprised me as well when I first found saw it. So - all I need is a way to know when I reached the button of the scrolldown  in order to exit the loop and save time.